# openui5 getBinding() returning undefined

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to listen to an event that indicates a custom control's aggregation binding has changed.

My goal is to locate the binding object associated with the aggregation and attach a handler to it.

I understand that binding occurs within onBeforeRendering, so I added an onAfterRendering function which is called successfully

However **this.getBinding("_myAggregation")** is still undefined, so that I cannot attach any event handler. The outline of the code is as follows:

```html
sap.ui.core.Control.extend("myControl",
  {
   metadata : {
    properties : {
    ...
    },
    aggregations : {
     _myAggregation : {
      type : "myInnerControl",
      multiple : false
     }
    },
    events : {
    ...
    }
   },
   init : function() {
    var self = this;
    self.setAggregation("_myAggregation", new myInnerControl.bindElement("queryModel>"));
   },
   onAfterRendering : function(oEvent) {
    if (sap.ui.core.Control.prototype.onAfterRendering) { 
     sap.ui.core.Control.prototype.onAfterRendering.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    this.getBinding("_myAggregation").attachChange(function() {
     alert("model change");
    });
   },
   renderer : function(oRm, oControl) {
    ...
   }
  });
```

I am using openui5 version 1.28.15
The application works otherwise: correctly renders the information in the JSONModel, handles edits etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this might help you.

http://jsbin.com/qagani/edit?html,js,output

The binding is more related to Managed Object rather than control itself.

Comment: That makes sense ... i *think*. In you example I presume mParameters is the oBindingInfo, referred to in [link](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#bindAggregation)

But how did you know that you could set events here? 

Also I assume the change event is that of a change of the bound data?

var mParameters = {
                model : "appView",
                path : "appView>/modelData",
                template : oButton1,
                events: {change : fnRecievedHandler}
        };

Comment: Yes you are right....mParameters is the oBindingInfo. I checked how to listed to different events of the binding. We can also listen to change, refresh, dataRequested,dataReceived etc, Provided you need to assign call back functions to each of them.

Comment: That clarifies it for me.

Have you ever managed to access the binding object directly (but your answer makes it clear it is not necessary)

Comment: yes you can do that too. And attach events separately provided metadata is already loaded and metadata is available.